# Less memory methods

Tags: c#, c++, c, pointers, methods

If i have the following methods:

```
void addfive(int num)
{
    num = num + 5;
}
```

and when i use it in the main routine like this:

```
int a = 15;
addfive(a);
```

What will happen is that 5 will be added to a copy of the (a) variable.
but if the method parameter is a pointer `int* num`  instead of the `int num
5` will be added to the (a) variable and no copy is created.

If I used the pointer in my method, will this use less memory that the first method, and will this work in non_void methods?

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you don't use a reference (`int &num`) [assuming C++]?

Comment: it's a bad idea to post some question for 3 languages using different rules for params

Comment: In C++, the version of the method you are showing could get optimized away, since it has no effect at all. In that case it would use *less* memory than one passing a pointer.

Comment: Please don't confuse the *conceptual semantics* with *what actually happens*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use a pointer it will still use memory and it will usually be less than the memory used by a type, but in your specific case and depending on your system (your os and application) an *int* * might use more memory than an *int*, use sizeof to see the size of a type and a pointer, example use this line in a 64 bit build of an application:

```
std::cout << "Size of int is: " << sizeof(int) << ", size of int* is: " << sizeof(int*) << "\n";
```

But another usage for pass by pointer or by reference is to be able to code your function to leave side-effects on the object (or build in type) that you pass as parameter.

Answer (score 0):

It's implementation defined whether passing a pointer takes more or less memory than passing an integer. For example, in MS Visual Studio `int` takes 4 bytes, and a pointer takes 4 bytes for 32-bit platform and 8 bytes for x64 system.

Usually `sizeof(int) <= sizeof(int*)` .

Answer (score 0):

Firsly +5 is applied to copy of "a" and

```
 int a = 15;
 addfive(a);
```

and your variable a will not change because "a" is passed by value not reference if you want a funciton that will change a you must use pointer or "ref" keyword

if you are using c or c++
your code should be likse this

```
addfilve(*a)
{
   *a = *a + 5;
}
int main()
{
int a = 15;
int *aptr ;
aptr = &a;

return 0;
}
```

but if you use c#

```
addfive(ref a)
{
  a += 5;
}
```

and when you want to use that function

```
double a = 5;
addfive(ref a); // a = 10 now
```

note that it is a normal funciton not extesion method

For example if you are writing form appilication it must be declared in the Form1 class